# display loader data in bootstrap form using $.each JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm trying to display json data loaded from php in a bootstrap form with one line
but not working with me

here is JAVASCRIPT

```
var req_='getprosp&id='+trdata.IDP;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "lib/read.php?req="+req_,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        global: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                $('input[name="'+i+'"]').val(data[i]);
            }
            //$.each(data, function(key, val) {console.log(val) });
        }
    });
```

thanks for helping

Comment: If you could specify please, 1) what are the contents of the the data json you receive back when it's a success, and 2) what isn't working, are you having any errors?

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` to make sure it isn't empty?

Comment: console.log(data) return object data
                             Object {PK_: "15865", NOM_: "EZZAR", PRENOM_: "TAOUFIK", CIBLAGE_: "A", NATURE_: "Publique"…}
CIBLAGE_
:
"A"
COMMANTAIRE_
:
null
EXERCANT_
:
"1"
FAX_
:
null
IDP
:
"15865"
LOC_
:
"HOP BEN AROUS/2096"
MOBILE_
:
null
NATURE_
:
"Publique"
NOM_
:
"EZZAR"
PK_
:
"15865"
PRENOM_
:
"TAOUFIK"
SPECIALITECODE_
:
"CARDIOLOGIE"
STATUS_
:
"Professeur_Agr�g�"
TELEPHONE_
:
null
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Please update your question with all additional information you have provided in comments and answers. (There is an edit link just below your question). You should not post clarifications as Answers.

Comment: Won't ever get any help if you post answers that aren't answers

Comment: *"not working with me"* is not a proper technical problem statement and is virtually meaningless when you don't identify more speifically what is or isn't working also

Comment: sorry but when trying to add same code i got this:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

for this reason i add answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked with this:

```
                            var req_='getprosp&id='+trdata.IDP;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "lib/read.php?req="+req_,

                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        global: false,
                        async: true,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {

                            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                //console.log(val)
                                var namef;
                                for(namef in val){
                                    console.log(namef + " = " + val[namef]);
                                    $('input[name="'+namef+'"]').val(val[namef]);
                                }

                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

sample form

```
        <div class="x_content" id="editForm" >
    <form role="form" id="prosp" action="" method="post"  >
                <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab_content1" aria-labelledby="home-tab">


                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="NOM_">Nom</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="NOM_" name="NOM_" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" data-bind="value: selected.NOM_" value="">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="PRENOM_">Pr&eacute;nom</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="PRENOM_" name="PRENOM_" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="" value="">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- nature-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="NATURE_">Nature</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <select id="NATURE_" name="NATURE_" class="form-control">
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        <option value="1">Publique</option>
                                        <option value="2">Priv&eacute;</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>                          

            </div>
        <br/>
        <button id="valider" type="submit" class=" btn btn-success" style="float: right">Valider</button>
    </form>
        </div>
```

console.log

Object {PK_: "15865", NOM_: "EZZAR", PRENOM_: "TAOUFIK", CIBLAGE_: "A", NATURE_: "Publique"…}